# More efficient way to map & reduce in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, dictionary, reduce

Let's say that you have a hash where the keys are Strings, and the values are Floats.  You want to group the values by a substring of each key, and then sum the values within each group.

Basically, you want to go from this:

```
{ "aaaapattern1aaaa" => 213.2342, "pattern2aaaa" => 0.03, 
  "aaaaapattern3" => 12.1, "pattern1aaa" => 54.4544, 
  "aaaaapattern2" => 65.003 }
```

to this:

```
{"pattern1"=>267.6886, "pattern2"=>65.033, "pattern3"=>12.1}
```

---

**Here is my current approach:**

```
data = {
  "aaaapattern1aaaa"=>213.2342, "pattern2aaaa"=>0.03, 
  "aaaaapattern3"=>12.1, "pattern1aaa"=>54.4544, 
  "aaaaapattern2"=>65.003
}

key_regexp = /pattern\d/

intermediate_results = data.map do |key, value| 
  { key.match(key_regexp)[0] => value } 
end

final_result = intermediate_results.reduce do |cumulative_hash, individual_hash| 
  cumulative_hash.merge(individual_hash) do |key, old_value, new_value| 
    old_value + new_value 
  end
end
```

How would you improve on this?  What factors should be considered in formulating an ideal approach?  Would your answer change based on the size of the Hash, and if so, how?

Comment: If you *group the values by a substring of each key*, then all values should be grouped together since all strings share the empty string as a substring. But your expected result seems to be different. Hence, your question is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a lot of work for what should be pretty simple:

```
sums = Hash.new(0)

d.each do |key, value|
  if (m = key.match(/pattern\d/))
    sums[m[0]] += value
  end
end

sums
# => {"pattern1"=>267.6886, "pattern2"=>65.033, "pattern3"=>12.1}
```

This has the advantage of ignoring anything that doesn't match.

Here `Hash.new(0)` creates a Hash that has a default value of `0`. This is a good pattern to use for assembling sums of arbitrary things.

Comment: Much simpler, and very idiomatic!  Thanks for this answer.

Comment: tadman, you might consider a couple of simplifications.  Rather than `key.match(/pattern\d/)` and `sums[m[0]]` you could use `key[/pattern\d/]` and `sums[m] += value`.  Further, you could  reduce it to `d.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |(key, value), sums| k = key[/pattern\d/]; sums[k] += value if k }`, which eliminates the need to reference `sums` before and after the block.

Comment: I'm a big fan of `each_with_object` but it does get a bit cluttered when using it on something already a hash where you need to break out `key` and `value` separately. For reasons of clarity I used `match`, though `String#[]` is a nice short-hand, and you do get a useful string back instead of a `MatchData` object.

Comment: I share your ambivalence regarding `each_with_object`, `with_object`, etc., for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

I think I would do something like the below. I can not say too much about the performance though.

```
sums = Hash.new(0) #Initialize hash with 0 as default
data.each do |k,v|
  case k #switch on the key
  when /pattern1/ #do regex pattern checks
   sums[:pattern_1] += v
  when /pattern2/
   sums[:pattern_2] += v
  else
    #undefined pattern
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use each_with_object you can make it rather compact.

Assuming `data` and `key_regexp` are as you defined:

```
data.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) do |(k,v),r|
  r[k.match(key_regexp)[0]] += v
end
```